# Determine if UNNotificationResponse is from watch extension or iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

When handling a location notification in the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` using `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` is it possible to determine if the user interacted with the notification using the watch app or on the iOS device?

Comment: You have to implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate twice - for iPhone and watches. Notifications will be received separately for iPhone and watches.

I recommend read this post: https://martiancraft.com/blog/2018/02/notification-handling-on-watchkit/

Answer (score 1):

> By default, if a notification arrives for an iOS app with a companion
>   WatchKit app, the system will first decide whether to display the
>   alert on the iPhone or the Apple Watch. In the event that the
>   notification is delivered to the Apple Watch a “short-look”
>   notification scene will first be displayed. This consists of the app
>   icon, the title from the notification and the name of the WatchKit app

check out this [tutorial](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_Notifications_in_WatchKit)

You have to implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate for both iPhone and Watchkit as well and take action accordingly.